# Multiple update laravel with checkbox

Tags: sql, laravel, checkbox

I have a table like the following

[image]

I want all the data I checked on his NIS changed all 0.

My code:

```html
<form action="{{url('update-tka25')}}" method="post"> 
              <div class="table table-responsive">
                <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered">
                  <thead>
                    <tr class="info">
                      <th>No</th>
                      <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" /></th>
                      <th>Data lengkap</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <?php $i = 1; ?>
                    @foreach( $datasiswa as $row )
                    <tr>
                      <td width="5%">{{ $i }}</td>
                      <td><input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="{{ $row->id }}" /></td>
                      <td width="95%">
                        <table class="table">
                          <tr>
                            <td class="info" width="20%">Nama lengkap</td>
                            <td width="30%">{{$row->nm_lengkap}}</td>
                            <td class="warning" width="20%">Nama ayah</td>
                            <td width="30%">{{$row->nm_ayah}}</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="info">NIS</td>
                            <td>{{$row->NIS}}</td>
                            <td class="warning">Pekerjaan Ayah</td>
                            <td>{{$row->pekerjaan_ayah}}</td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php $i++; ?>
                    @endforeach
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-10">
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-block"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Update</button>
                </form>
```

JS

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
                  $('#selectAll').click(function(e){
                    var table= $(e.target).closest('table');
                    $('td input:checkbox',table).prop('checked',this.checked);
                  });
                </script>
```

I repeat

My question is how do I update the NIS data to 0 from the data I've checkedlist?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Show your code

Comment: Code I've posted, for the front end is it correct? What about the controller?

Comment: you will get array of ids from check box and simply use that in laravel WhereIn('key',$array)  like  whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3]) in your update query and you are Done with your expected update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have `id[]` as an array, that's good. It means you can send a lot of IDs to the backend. In your backend function do

```
public function foo(Request $request)
{
    $ids = $request->id;

    DB::table('tablename')->whereIn('id', $ids)
    ->update(['NIS' => 0]);
}
```